# CodeFirst mapping relationship between entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Having these 2 entities:

```
public partial class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

How do I map the relationship so that Title is required in Person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Title);
}
```